# How do I tell MAAS which drive to boot from?

Tags: maas

I am using MAAS to deploy a bunch of systems for OpenStack and I can't figure out how to tell it which drive to use as the boot drive. It seems to just pick whichever drive it wants.

I am using MAAS 1.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the preseed files in /etc/maas/preseeds

These control the disk config used by maas to create operating systems.  Specifically, look for the "Partitioning" section.  It does a

```
partman list-devices disk|head -n1
```

This is configurable.  See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt
   https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs02.html

For more info